# I'm trying to add properties to an object, but only the last is being attached

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create this object with values coming from others objects

```
let arr = [
  { name: "Ashley", n: 241 },
  { name: "Deborah", n: 347 },
  { name: "Jessica", n: 307 }
];

let arr = [];
graphData.forEach(e => {
  arr.push(e);
  if(arr.length === 7){
    let o = {};
    arr.forEach(a => {
      let name = e.name;
      o[name] = +a.n
    });
    o["chartDate"] = new Date(e.chartDate);
    this.data.push(o);
    arr = [];
  }
});
```

Instead of getting

```
{ 
   Ashley: 241,
   Deborah: 347,
   Jessica: 307 
}
```

I'm getting only the last property

```
{ 
   Jessica: 307 
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined`. And if I change that to `a.name` it seems to work fine.

Comment: After fixing that typo the code works properly.

Comment: You **significantly** changed the code. Why?

Comment: Because, I overlooked the fact that I didn't put the entire block. Someone complained about the `e`.

Comment: The code as posted does not make sense.

Comment: There is 2 `let arr` which should throw an error.

Comment: @Pointy, feel free to vote down the questions, but don't vote the answers that are correct.

Comment: You have asked 600 questions. Posting a [mcve] which doesn't have obvious errors like two `let arr` statements is the absolute bare minimum requirement

Comment: @adiga, you can't delete a question when people have answered. Also, did you checked my profile?

Comment: So the accepted answer is basically the *original* code with the typo fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fix your code:

```js
let arr = [
  { name: "Ashley", n: 241 },
  { name: "Deborah", n: 347 },
  { name: "Jessica", n: 307 }
];

let o = {};
arr.forEach(a => {
  let name = a.name;
  o[name] = a.n
});
console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use reduce in such scenarios

```js
let arr = [
  { name: "Ashley", n: 241 },
  { name: "Deborah", n: 347 },
  { name: "Jessica", n: 307 }
];

const obj =  arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  prev[curr.name] = curr.n;
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```